# scikit-learn PCA remove common signals

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

Traditionally PCA is used to reduce dimensionality (I believe) but I want to use it to remove trends.

My use case is that I have lots of time series (star brightnesses) and want to remove spurious signals which are present in lots of these time series. I believe PCA can be used for determining these basis functions, but how can I then remove them from the full dataset?

I have tried e.g.

```
pca = PCA(n_components=4)
pca.fit(lightcurves)

detrended = lightcurves / (pca.components_ * pca.explained_variance_ratio_)
```

Is this possible with PCA?

For example, I have a lot of time series which have similar features, such as the one below. Every night the star gets brighter towards the highest point of its positioning on the sky, and then gets fainter. Each object undergoes this (it's an artefact of looking through the atmosphere) so surely it's something PCA can pick out, such that it can be removed?

[image: Example light curve]

Comment: Can you post an example of this "spurious noise" and the expected output you are looking for? This question may be a better fit for http://dsp.stackexchange.com/ since it is not _directly_ related to programing.

Comment: @Hooked thanks for your suggestion, I've added an example lightcurve. I understand it may be related to the stack exchange board you suggested, but I'm specifically asking about the python implementation of PCA and how to use it, rather than the concept in particular.

Comment: Are your time series aligned? I'm not sure PCA is the best tool for the job, but you could try using ``transform`` and just dropping the first component, for example. But you should look at the components first ;)